# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{2n}{2r}3^r}{\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2r+1}3^r}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, limits

Evaluate :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{2n}{2r}3^r}{\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2r+1}3^r}$$

The answer given is $\sqrt3$. Frankly,  have no clue where to begin. I thought of putting it under binomial expansion like this $(1+3)^{2n}$. But it's not leading anywhere.

Please prvide only Hints. I want to solve it using the hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$(1+x)^{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \dbinom{2n}k x^k$$
$$(1-x)^{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \dbinom{2n}k (-x)^k$$
Hence,
$$\dfrac{(1+x)^{2n} + (1-x)^{2n}}2 = \sum_{k=0,2,}^{2n} \dbinom{2n}k x^k = \sum_{r=0}^n \dbinom{2n}{2r} x^{2r}$$
$$\dfrac{(1+x)^{2n} - (1-x)^{2n}}2 = \sum_{k=1,3,}^{2n-1} \dbinom{2n}k x^k = \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \dbinom{2n}{2r+1} x^{2r+1}$$
Taking $x = \sqrt{3}$ and massage to obtain the answer.